# Show CCSprites with a delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I am a beginner in Cocos2d and I wanted to display coin sprites as soon as it moves off the screen with a 5 second delay. So this is what I wrote in my main gameplay layer to add 7 coins in a row:

```
- (void)coinSidewaysRowOne { 
    if (coinSide1 == FALSE)
    {
        coinSide1 = TRUE;
        NSLog(@"coinSide1 = TRUE");
        int originalX = 500;
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            CCSprite *coinHorizontal = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bubble.png"];
            coinHorizontal.position = ccp(originalX, 150);
            originalX += 20;

            [self addChild:coinHorizontal];
            [coinArray addObject:coinHorizontal];
        }
    }
}
```

And then, in my updateRunning method I added this, so when the coins spawn outside the screen, they move to the left and disappear:

```
// Move coins off the screen and make them move away
    for (CCSprite *coin in coinArray) {
        // apply background scroll speed
        float backgroundScrollSpeedX = [[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] backGroundScrollSpeedX];
        float xSpeed = 1.09 * backgroundScrollSpeedX;

        // move the coin until it leaves the left edge of the screen
        if (coin.position.x > (coin.contentSize.width * (-1)))
        {
            coin.position = ccp(coin.position.x - (xSpeed*delta), coin.position.y);
        }
    }
```

So right now, when I run this, the coins move in from the right and move off the screen from the left.
How do I make it so that when the coins move to the left and go off the screen, have a five second delay and then have new coins come back to the screen from the right like it originally did.

Thank you!

Comment: When testing Objective C booleans (BOOL), try to get in the habit of testing and setting them as YES or NO instead of TRUE, FALSE, true or false as it is the standard used in all of Apple's libraries. Also, when testing boolean values, you can leave out the == true bit. A simple if (CGRectIntersectsRect(knightRect, coinRect)) would suffice. It helps clean up your code :)

Comment: Thank you for the improvement

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call one function which will add that sprite back the screen with delay of five seconds.

You have to add some code as follows:

```
for (CCSprite *coin in coinArray)
{
    // apply background scroll speed
    float backgroundScrollSpeedX = [[GameMechanics sharedGameMechanics] backGroundScrollSpeedX];
    float xSpeed = 1.09 * backgroundScrollSpeedX;

    // move the coin until it leaves the left edge of the screen
    if (coin.position.x > (coin.contentSize.width * (-1)))
    {
        coin.position = ccp(coin.position.x - (xSpeed*delta), coin.position.y);
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(showSpriteAgain:) withObject:coin afterdelay:5.0f];
    }
}
```

And make one function which will add that sprite to screen again:

```
-(void) showSpriteAgain:(CCSprite *)coin 
{
coin.position = ccp(coin.position.x+screenSize.width,coin.position.y);
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much, but adding `[self performSelector:@selector(showSpriteAgain) withObject:coin afterdelay:5.0f];` gives me an error `No visible @interface for 'GamePlayLayer' declares the selector 'performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:'`

Comment: hey check i have changed the answer, now it will not give error. you just have to put ":" at @selector(showSpriteAgain:)

Comment: For some reason, it still gives me that same error... I tried changing self to coin but still no luck...

Comment: What is the type of your GamePlayLayer interface ? is it CCLayer?

Comment: It's this `@interface GameplayLayer : CCLayer <StoreDisplayNeedsUpdate>` So yes, CCLayer

Comment: mine interface is also the same,but not giving error. Try to seach that on google like: No visible @interface

Comment: Oh, haha, the problem was a typo. afterdelay should be afterDelay. Thank you!